# I need to group (tbl_types.name AS type) in a same row (postgres 14)

Tags: sql, database, group-by, postgresql-14

I need help with a select in postgres, I need to group X types into a single line, for example: type: multiple, trully, I need help on the type column

```
SELECT tbl_questions.id AS id,
 tbl_questions.question AS question, 
 tbl_questions.year AS year, 
 tbl_question_responses.response_id AS response_id, 
 tbl_responses.response AS response_content, 
 tbl_responses.response_type AS response, 
 tbl_subjects.name AS subject,
 tbl_categories.name AS category,
 tbl_types.name AS type,
 tbl_institutions.name AS institution
FROM tbl_questions  

INNER JOIN tbl_question_responses ON tbl_questions.id = tbl_question_responses.question_id
INNER JOIN tbl_responses ON tbl_question_responses.response_id = tbl_responses.id

INNER JOIN tbl_question_subjects ON tbl_questions.id = tbl_question_subjects.question_id
INNER JOIN tbl_subjects ON tbl_subjects.id = tbl_question_subjects.subject_id

INNER JOIN tbl_question_categories ON tbl_questions.id = tbl_question_categories.question_id
INNER JOIN tbl_categories ON tbl_categories.id = tbl_question_categories.category_id

INNER JOIN tbl_question_types ON tbl_questions.id = tbl_question_types.question_id
INNER JOIN tbl_types ON tbl_types.id = tbl_question_types.type_id

INNER JOIN tbl_question_institutions ON tbl_question_institutions.question_id = tbl_questions.id
INNER JOIN tbl_institutions ON tbl_institutions.id = tbl_question_institutions.institution_id

WHERE tbl_questions.id = 'c7aa15cb-27e5-4f28-9141-483f7cce8e56'
```

[This is a select result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5Gyb.png)

Comment: Postgres or MySQL? Please do not tag databases not involved.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.